# MCP must specify URI Scheme in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, uri, minecraft

I recently became interested in Minecraft modding, so I downloaded MCP (Minecraft Coder Pack) and Eclipse. After running decompile.bat, I opened Eclipse using the workspace provided by MCP. At first I was given a list of errors related to missing libraries, but I easily fixed that by fixing their paths. Then I continued following the video tutorial I was using and pressed "Run" and selected "Client" as the project to run. Eclipse gave me the following error:

Must specify a URI scheme:MCP_LOC/jars

I have been Googling this for the past 20 minutes with no success. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

I can probably still program mods for Minecraft and even recompile them with MCP, but it will be difficult to test them. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEVER START IN ECLIPSE**

Try [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UdFa7dB2kc/%22This%22) vid for 1.7.3
Its a nice little series about minecraft modding.

Comment: Wow, thanks! And here I thought this topic died long ago without a single answer.